# IF statement in SQL WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Is it possible to pass in a value to a stored procedure to tell it whether or not to append an OR statement to a SQL SELECT statement?

I've tried something like so but it is not valid:

```
SELECT xyzName
FROM xyz_fields
WHERE (xyzType = 'this') UNION ALL
(if @status=1 OR (xyzType = 'that')) UNION ALL
(if @status2=1 OR (xyzType = 'somethingelse'))
```

Kind of like building up the WHERE clause in SQL rather than hitting the DB again from the application?

Comment: try to use case statements. please post data you have and what output you need..

Comment: you'll have to be more specific... your query doesnt make sense and the question is confusing also...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Dynamic SQL for this.

```
declare @SqlQuery varchar(100)

Set @SqlQuery = ' SELECT xyzName FROM xyz_fields WHERE  xyzType = ''this'' '

if(@status=1)
Set @SqlQuery = @SqlQuery + ' OR xyzType = ''that'' '

if(@status2=1)
Set @SqlQuery = @SqlQuery + ' OR xyzType = ''somethingelse'''

exec(@SqlQuery)
```

Single qoutes in query  are escaped by prefixing another single qoute.
So in query

```
WHERE  xyzType = 'this'
```

should be

```
WHERE  xyzType = ''this''
```

Comment: Seems like this may be a good way to go, I will give it a go and mark as answer if correct. +1 for effort though, thanks!

Comment: UPDATE: This seems to work well, many thanks for posting this solution.

Comment: If you're going to use dynamic SQL, you should use `UNION ALL` against multiple queries rather than `OR`s. You'll generally get a better query plan. For example, `SELECT * FROM A WHERE 'X' UNION ALL SELECT * FROM B WHERE 'Y'`

Comment: Much better solution to use an OR rather than dynamic SQL. You add un-needed securty issues by using dynamic sql.

Comment: What is your application written in? There may be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 4):

I think you mean something like this:

```
SELECT xyzName
FROM xyz_fields
WHERE (xyzType = 'this') 
OR (@status=1 AND (xyzType = 'that')) 
OR (@status2=1 AND (xyzType = 'somethingelse'))
```

The second line of the where clause delivers only success when @status equals 1 and xyzType equals 'that'.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT xyzName
FROM xyz_fields
WHERE (xyzType = 'this')
OR ((xyzType = 'that') AND @status = 1)
OR ((xyzType = 'somethingelse') AND @status2 = 1)
```

When `@status = 1`, `((xyzType = 'that') AND @status = 1)` returns `(xyzType = 'that')`,
but when `@status = 0`, `((xyzType = 'that') AND @status = 1)` returns `false` and will not affect your query.